# Passing Data between directive/component via service

Tags: angular, service, components, directive, subscribe

I'm attempting to pass data from a directive to a component via a service.
The return from my transfer service file says that the *type 'Transfer' is not assignable to Observer*. I also get '*Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '() => Observable*' in my component file when trying to subscribe to the service. Why is this and how can I fix it?
my files are

**transfer.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Transfer } from './transfer';

@Injectable()
export class TransferService {

  constructor(private transfer: Transfer){}

  private pageData;
  private contentData;
  private contentBox;

  setData(pData, cData, bData){
    this.pageData = pData;
    this.contentData = cData;
    this.contentBox = bData;
  }

  getData(): Observable<Transfer>{
    this.transfer.page = this.pageData;
    this.transfer.content = this.contentData;
    this.transfer.contentBox = this.contentBox;
    this.clearData();
    return this.transfer;
  }

  clearData(){
    this.pageData = undefined;
    this.contentData = undefined;
    this.contentBox = undefined;
  }
}
```

**transfer.ts**

```
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
export interface Transfer{
    page: [
        {
            pageNum: number,
            subStart: number,
            subEnd: number
        }   
    ];
    content: string;
    contentBox: ElementRef;
}
```

**article.component.ts** - component

```
  transfer(){
    this.ts.getData.subscribe(data => this.tsData = data);
  }
```

**paginator.ts** - directive

```
// Pass date via transferservice.ts
transfer(){
  this.ts.setData(this.pageJump, this.content, this.contentBox);
}
```

**EDIT:** 
using @ritaj's solution resolved the issue of not being assignable/property not existing, but now I'm getting '*Error: Can't resolve all parameters for TransferService*'

**STACKBLITZ EDIT:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mesh

Comment: Have you passed TransferService  in your component constructor.?

Comment: You don't need a service method to _return_ one of its properties. You can access it directly from the component (assuming the service is injected in it and that `transfer` is public) using `this.ts.transfer.subscribe()`.

Comment: @berensn , Can you show it on Stackblitz?

Comment: @JeremyThille I tried your solution but 'subscribe() is not a property of type transfer' so would I add it to my transfer.ts file somewhere to get it functional?

Answer (score 0):

Your `getData()` service method does NOT return Observable, as you have `type`d.

It just returns a normal JS object, which does not have .subscribe() method, obviously.

Change your `article.component.ts` `transfer()` method to this:

```
transfer(){
    this.tsData = this.ts.getData();
  }
```

And change getData signature to:

```
getData(): Transfer {}
```

Answer (score 0):

### article.component.ts

```
  constructor(public ts : TransferService){}
  transfer(){
     this.tsData = this.ts.getData();   // directly call
  }
```

### Inject the service in app.module.ts :-

```
providers:[TransferService]
```

Here is Stackblitz link, just a demo to reflect solution to the problem:-

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-service-example-onwtg6?file=app/article.component.ts